# Are Prior Publications allowed in IEEE Transactions on Information Theory?

Tags: journals, conference, ieee, extended-paper

I have a paper written that is about 17 pages. I plan to submit a shortened version of it of only the main ideas to a conference with a 10 page limit next month, but I also want to submit the full manuscript for review to IEEE Transactions on Information Theory in parallel. I was reading their FAQ and I read the following paragraph which really confused me:

> **Policy on prior publication**
>
> Contributions should comprise novel and
>   previously unpublished material; however, prior publication at (or
>   parallel submission to) conferences does not preclude publication in
>   this Transactions, provided this is properly referenced in the paper
>   at the time of submission to the Transactions. Thereafter, submission
>   to other journals is precluded, unless the paper is rejected by this
>   Transactions, or is withdrawn. If all or part of the paper was
>   previously presented at one or more conferences, a statement such as
>   the following must be included in the authors' footnote on the first
>   page of the paper at the time of submission: "This paper was presented
>   [in part] at ... [and ...]."
>
> If authors submit a paper that is a nearly verbatim copy of a prior
>   conference publication, they have to indicate to the editors in a
>   cover letter why they feel that republication is warranted. Editorial
>   decisions will take into account any previous publication of submitted
>   material.

Here is what's confusing me. At first, they say that its okay to have parallel submission as long as this is referenced in the paper. Then they say but we have to indicate this to the editors with a cover letter. I am confused, is what I am doing okay or not?

Comment: In the cover letter, simply indicate that the paper has been published by conference X (or in submission at X), and then list all the new items/parts in the journal submission that are not in the conference version.  The editor can then make up his/her mind whether the new parts are sufficiently different.   Usually parallel submissions are a waste of time because you would want to get some feedback first before going for a journal.  Also note that conferences usually do not allow parallel submissions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no confusion, you can present the paper in the conference and submit it for publication.

But you have to tell the editors in a letter with the paper which conference it was presented at.

This is so that they know at the time and don’t find out “by accident” or, you never know, they could be at the conference...

Comment: Wouldn't this count as double publication with the conference proceedings?

Comment: "however, prior publication at (or parallel submission to) conferences does not preclude publication" taken from what you quoted.